# How to pass parameter to whereHas() clause in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I queried the Category model to get all the ids where `'name', '=', $name` to use to query the Post model but I get an error.

```php
public function getList($name)
{
    $category_id = Category::where('name', '=', $name)->first()->id;

    $posts = Post::whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($category_id) {
        $q->where('id', '=', $category_id);
    })->paginate(12);

    return view('blog.index')->withPosts($posts)->withName($name);
}
```

Here's my error.

> ErrorException in Builder.php line 877: compact(): Undefined variable:
>   operator

Comment: am still getting the error

Comment: In your question you have posted an error that states "Undefined variable operator" but i don't see any variable named "operator".

Comment: try returning `view('blog.index', compact('posts', 'name'))`

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Answer (score 6):

If u are still looking for this

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('category', function (Builder $q) use ($category_id) {
    $q->where('id', '=', $category_id);
})->paginate(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set all same as me, all will run well!

The relation of posts and categories table is ManyMany. So you need a pivot table name category_post to contain data relations 2 tables:

```
Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

In Post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_post','post_id','category_id');
    }
}
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_post','category_id','post_id');
    }
}
```

And YourController:

```
public function getList($name)
{
    $category_id = Category::where('name', '=', $name)->first()->id;

    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($category_id) {
        $q->where('category_id', '=', $category_id);
    })->paginate(12);

    return view('show')->withPosts($posts)->withName($name);
}
```

Happy coding! Ask me if you need!